# char* to string from while loop

Tags: c++, string

Trying to relearn C/C++ 
why is it when I run this:

```
char* tmp;

while ((tmp =  strtok(itr->c_str(),' ')) != NULL ) {
          std::string s(tmp);
           cout << "S " << s<< endl;
}
```

I obtain this:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/basic_string.h:437:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

It is either that or I do not have enough arguments. I know tmp is not NULL because I am checking it in my while loop.
It also happens when I try string s = string(tmp);

I see the documentation and I thought I copied it down similarly except for my needs. I am obviously missing something.

Any feed back please?

Comment: Please post the *full* error message, preferably with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy, paste, and run.

Comment: your error might not be in this code segment.

Comment: Given that you've accepted Ben's answer, I am extremely curious what the rest of the error is, because it currently makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `strtok` on a constant string because it actually overwrites delimiters with NUL terminators, so this won't work

```
strtok(itr->c_str(),' ')
```

Your loop also doesn't perform the right steps to get multiple tokens from the same string.

Since you want each token copied into a separate `string` instance anyway, consider using `std::string`'s `find` member functions along with `substr`, and avoiding `strtok` completely.  Many different examples given on [the canonical question about splitting a std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/236129/103167)  The exact approach I suggested is seen [in one of the answers there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408245/103167).

Comment: followed your advice using substr, find. I had no need for strtok. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ben that there are better ways to do this, but FWIW will show how to [fix your code](http://ideone.com/BH3OmX).  Note in particular the use of `&s[0]` (in your case `&(*itr)[0]`) to get a (writable) `char*` into the string, and that after the first call a `nullptr` must be passed to subsequent `strtok` invocations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "first second third fourth fifth sixth";
    for (char* tmp = std::strtok(&s[0], " "); tmp;
         tmp = std::strtok(nullptr, " "))
    {
        std::string field(tmp);  // can "<< tmp <<" below directly....
        std::cout << "S " << field << '\n';
    }
}
```

I believe C++11 was the first C++ Standard to mandate a contiguous buffer for `std::string`, so the code above is not guaranteed to work with earlier versions, though in practice all `std::string` implementations I've ever heard of used contiguous memory (as distinct from STL's `rope`).

Comment: Yes, this takes care of both problems I saw, plus the separator-should-be-string-not-single-character error.  I would suggest using different names for the two different `std::string` variables, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @BenVoigt: oh - hadn't even noticed the dual uses of `s` - cheers.